# Can I dim a timer control in a asp.net server dll and add a tick event that fires every 30 seconds inside the server dll Im creating?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

Asp.Net question. Can I dim a timer control in a server dll and add a tick event that fires every 30 seconds inside the server dll Im creating? Asp.Net question. Can I dim a timer control in a server dll and add a tick event that fires every 30 seconds inside the server dll Im creating?

Answer (score 1):

There is no Timer control in ASP.NET WebForms, there *is* a Timer component that's used with ASP.NET AJAX Extensions (documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386404(v=vs.100).aspx ) however it is used to fire client-side eevents.

You cannot instantiate `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` in ASP.NET for obvious reasons.

You *can* use `System.Timers.Timer` and `System.Threading.Timer` (the difference is explained here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx ).

You will need to respond to the timer callbacks in a separate thread which means they won't have anything to do with your pages, instead use it for background processing, however this is not recommended because your ASP.NET worker process (w3wp.exe) will be killed and recycled without warning or notice. If you must have continuous background processing on regular intervals then use a Windows Service instead of ASP.NET.